# Codeigniter with ajax alerts wampserver homepage

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, wampserver

I am new to codeigniter and I am trying some ajax functionalities with it. Following [ajax-codeigniter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-codeigniter/) , my view is

```
<?php
$set_price_range_500_1500 = array(
    "name"=>"price_range",
    "value" => "500-1500",
    "id" => "pr_500_1500"
    );
?>
<?php echo form_checkbox($set_price_range_500_1500); ?>
<?php echo lang('price_range_500_1500'); ?>
```

And the jquery resides in `ci\themes\default\assets\js\`:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pr_500_1500").click(function(){
        var range = $("pr_500_1500").val();

        $.post(
               '/index.php/ajax/getPricerangeProducts',
               {'range' : range },

               function( result )
               {
                    if( result )
                    {
                        alert( result ) ;   
                    }
               }
               );
    });
});
```

And the controller `ajax` residing in `ci\controllers\` :

```
<?php
class ajax extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__contruct();
    }

    function getPricerangeProducts()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

But instead of alerting `hello`, it alerts the `wampserver` homepage !

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you visit `http://yourdomain.com/index.php/ajax/getPricerangeProducts` in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this and try:

```
$.post(
'<?=base_url()?>/index.php/ajax/getPricerangeProducts',
{'range' : range },

function( result )
{
    if( result )
    {
        alert( result ) ;   
    }
}
);
```